# Getting ValueAnimator value out to onDraw

Tags: android, canvas

I'm confused with instructions in this page [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-bring-life-to-your-custom-view-8604ab3967b3). Working on the below function.

```
PropertyValuesHolder propertyRadius = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt(PROPERTY_RADIUS, 0, 150);
PropertyValuesHolder propertyRotate = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt(PROPERTY_ROTATE, 0, 360);

animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setValues(propertyRadius, propertyRotate);
animator.setDuration(2000);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        radius = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_RADIUS);
        rotate = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_ROTATE);
        invalidate();
    }
});
animator.start();
```

He stated that calling this method to do the rotation. As I did was declaring "radius" and "rotate" variable in global and put below code to "onDraw" method so invalidate will update Canvas.

```
canvas.rotate(rotate, viewWidth, viewHeight);
```

Problem: I can't seems to get the "radius" or "rotate" variable out of below code. It keeps returning "0" when I inserted a log inside OnDraw to check on "rotate" value. I'm still learning about this canvas thingy.

```
 public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        radius = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_RADIUS);
        rotate = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_ROTATE);
        invalidate();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

here is my full code:

```
public class DrawingShapes extends View {
    private String PROPERTY_ROTATE = "PROPERTY_ROTATE", PROPERTY_RADIUS = "PROPERTY_RADIUS";

    private Context mContext;

    private int radius, rotate;


    public DrawingShapes(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawingShapes(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawAnim();
        Log.i("TAG", "checking DrawingShapes rotate = " + rotate);

    }
    

    public static int convertDpToPixel(Context context, int idp) {
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) idp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    public void drawAnim() {
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyRadius = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt(PROPERTY_RADIUS, 0, 150);
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyRotate = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt(PROPERTY_ROTATE, 0, 360);

        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
        animator.setValues(propertyRadius, propertyRotate);
        animator.setDuration(100);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                radius = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_RADIUS);
                rotate = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_ROTATE);
                Log.i("TAG", "checking DrawingShapes rotate = " + rotate);
                invalidate();
            }
        });

        animator.start();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `animation.getAnimatedValue(PROPERTY_RADIUS)` returns?

Comment: it returns values from 0.... 150. I've tried insert a Log inside it will generate value, but if I move the Log to onDraw it will always be "0"

Comment: Can you produce a [mre] so it can be tested? So just a simple view class that has the animator and logs in `onDraw`.

Comment: @HenryTwist kindly check on the updated part

Comment: You're starting the animation *in* `onDraw`, which doesn't make any sense. When you then call `invalidate`, `onDraw` will be called again, which will then start another animation, call `onDraw` again etc. You should be starting the animation when you want it to start, like when the view is instantiated, or manually if it responds to some sort of trigger.

Comment: @HenryTwist I still don't get it, does it mean that this ValueAnimator function need to be declare in a separate class? cause what my intention was just getting the "radius" or "rotate" value from inside ValueAnimator to update the canvas.DrawRoundRect() function

Comment: The class is irrelevant, it's the fact that you're *calling it* from `onDraw` that is the issue. Every time the view should change its appearance (every frame of an animation etc), `onDraw` is called, so starting an animation here makes no sense. `onDraw` should only be used for **drawing**.

Comment: @HenryTwist I've finally got it and able to produce the result as expected !!! Thanks to your guidance to clear my understanding. cheers~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting the animation in `onDraw`, which doesn't make any sense. `onDraw` should only be used for **drawing**, not anything else.

To highlight why it would be nonsensical, consider what your code is actually doing:

`onDraw` starts the animation, which repeatedly calls `invalidate`. This then triggers `onDraw` to be called again, which then starts another animation, which repeatedly calls `invalidate`, ...., etc.

You should be starting the animation when you want it to start, like when the view is instantiated, or manually if it responds to some sort of trigger. For example:

```
class DrawingShapes ... {

    private int radius;

    DrawingShapes(...) {

        ...
        startAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        
        drawCircleWithRadius(radius);
    }

    private void startAnimation() {

        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
        ...
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                radius = ...
                invalidate();
            }
        });

        animator.start();
    }
}
```